# postgresql change character varying to character varying array

Tags: sql, postgresql

below I have two columns in table. they both say they are character varying but zoning_description has an array symbol after it. I need to change the zoning column to match the zoning_description column type. how do I accomplish this.

Also what is the difference between these two column types...
I am running into an error later in a different process because of this problem

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just alter type with casting, eg your table:

```
t=# create table z as select '{R}'::varchar zoning, '{"Blah-ah ah"}'::varchar[] zoning_description;
SELECT 1
t=# select * from z;
 zoning | zoning_description
--------+--------------------
 {R}    | {"Blah-ah ah"}
(1 row)
```

alter type:

```
t=# alter table z alter column zoning type varchar[] using zoning::varchar[];
ALTER TABLE
t=# select * from z;
 zoning | zoning_description
--------+--------------------
 {R}    | {"Blah-ah ah"}
(1 row)
```

checking columns:

```
t=# \d z
                            Table "postgres.z"
       Column       |        Type         | Collation | Nullable | Default
--------------------+---------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 zoning             | character varying[] |           |          |
 zoning_description | character varying[] |           |          |
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `zoning_description` is an array of `VARCHAR` values, while `zoning` is just a `VARCHAR`.  If you want to convert `zoning` to be the same data type as `zoning_description`, you can just do:

```
SELECT ARRAY[zoning]
```

This will CAST it as an array data type.

**Working query**

```
SELECT 
    MyVarchar, 
    PG_TYPEOF(MyVarchar),  -- character varying
    MyVarcharArray, 
    PG_TYPEOF(MyVarcharArray),  -- character varying[]
    ARRAY[MyVarchar], 
    PG_TYPEOF(ARRAY[MyVarchar])  -- character varying[]
FROM (
    SELECT 
    CAST('rammstein' AS VARCHAR) AS MyVarchar, 
    ARRAY[CAST('du hast' AS VARCHAR)] AS MyVarcharArray
) src
```

Comment: `with z as (select '{R}'::varchar zoning, '{"Blah"}'::varchar[] zoning_description)
select *,array[zoning] from z;`